# Google Sign In on Android only work with one of my accounts

Tags: java, android

I am currently making an Android game and I am using google sign in (for access to firebase, google leaderboard and achievement). I already integrated all of that and this is working fine. However I was always using my main google account but when I tried to change it to another account to have other people test it, it doesn't connect anymore.

I added the other account as a tester on the google play game service for my app. I believe I must have missed to add it somewhere but I cannot find where and I have been searching for hours.

Here's the code that should connect but doesn't:

```
private void startSignInIntent() {
        Intent intent = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
                GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_SIGN_IN:

                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    GoogleSignInAccount x = result.getSignInAccount();
                    //x.getIdToken() is always null with the other account
                    if (x.getIdToken() != null)
                        firebaseConnect(x);
                    else
                        //I tried repeating the operation but won't work

                    (...)
```

I also tried with different accounts but only my original one works. So do you have any idea of what I could have done that made this original account work and not any other? I did most of that Google Sign in parametrization long time ago so I don't remember in every details. And I am very desperate to debug that, after spending so much time trying to solve it in vain.

Thank you for any hint or help about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I used "GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN" but we need to use "GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN" to use google connection. For more details about the difference between these 2, refer to the GoogleSignInOptions API documentation.